# Matrix creation

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I  have many documents containing string as shown below.

```
[('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'NN'),   ('PP',
'TO'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('NP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'CD'), ('NP', 'JJ'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('
PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', '
DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('
NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'JJ'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('WHNP', 'WDT'), ('NP', 'JJS'), ('NP', '
CD'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('VP', 'VBP'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('NP', 'PRP'),
('VP', 'VBD'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('WHADVP', 'WRB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP
', 'NNS'), ('NP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('PRT', 'RP'), ('NP', 'PRP
'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('N
P', 'NN'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NN')]
```

I want to create a matrix in excel where each of this unique syntactic category pairs like ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'DT') act as column heading with their respective frequency.

Second , Third documents may contain syntactic category pairs which is not there in document one. So the syntactic pair which is not there must be appended in the column heading .

In the end I want to create a  matrix in which the column specifies the syntactic pairs and rows specifies different documents. Each entry Mij in matrix should indicate how often jth syntactic pair occurred in the ith document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `collections` module to count the frequency of your pairs

```
import collections
doc1 = [('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'NN'),   ('PP','TO'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('NP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'CD'), ('NP', 'JJ'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'JJ'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('WHNP', 'WDT'), ('NP', 'JJS'), ('NP', 'CD'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('VP', 'VBP'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('NP', 'PRP'),('VP', 'VBD'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('WHADVP', 'WRB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('NP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('PRT', 'RP'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('PP', 'IN'), ('NP', 'NN')]
count1 = collections.Counter(doc1)
```

This gives you

```
count1.keys()
>>>[('PP', 'IN'), ('WHADVP', 'WRB'), ('NP', 'NNS'), ('WHNP', 'WDT'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('NP', 'JJS'), ('NP', 'DT'), ('NP', 'CD'), ('ADVP', 'RB'), ('PRT', 'RP'), ('VP', 'VBD'), ('NP', 'JJ'), ('NP', 'RB'), ('VP', 'VBP'), ('NP', 'PRP'), ('PP', 'TO')]

count1.values()
>>>[5, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 9, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 1]
```

Do this for each document

Afterwards you need to transform the values into a list with tree values.
In this case numpy arrays are easier to handle.

```
import numpy as np

for key in pairs1.key()
     pairs1[key] = np.array([pairs1[key],0,0])

for key in pairs2.key()
     pairs2[key] = np.array([0,pairs2[key],0])

for key in pairs3.key()
     pairs3[key] = np.array([0,0,pairs3[key]])
```

Then you merge all three dictionaries together:

```
pairs = {}

for key in pairs1.keys():
    pairs[key] = pairs[key]

for key in pairs2.keys():
    try:
        pairs[key] = pairs[key] + pairs2[key]
    except KeyError:
        pairs[key] = pairs2[key]

for key in pairs3.keys():
    try:
        pairs[key] = pairs[key] + pairs3[key]
    except KeyError:
        pairs[key] = pairs3[key]
```

In the end you can give out your matrix

```
f = open('myfile.csv','w')
header = ''
for key in pairs.keys():
    if header == '':
        header = '%s' %pairs[key]
    else:
        header = '%s, %s' % (header, pairs[key])
f.write('%s\n' % header)

for i in range(4):
    line = ''
    for value in pairs.values():
        if line == '':
            line = '%s' %pairs[value][i]
        else:
            header = '%s, %s' % (header, pairs[value][i])
    f.write('%s\n' % line)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually i have thousands documents like this.Is there any way by which i can automate this process for thousands document, instead of manually entering them.

Comment: Well build a for loop around the part where you read in the key/value pairs. My solution is quick and dirty. You should be able to write this using less variables. (one for the final dictonary, the other one for file you read during the for loop)